Perl: makes array of item IDs shortened
I have a large set of numbers, basically 1001 .. 150000 for a database using MySQL
There are a ton of gaps in the IDs on the database, so not all IDs exist. It can go from 100000 - 10500, then the next number will be 10675, and so forth.
I want to make the IDs shortened, such as 1001..3000, x, x, x, 55000..101000, etc.
I'm sure it's simple.
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE data = x 

give me above info.
I used
select group_concat(id) from items where id>1000

to get all ids in a comma-separated list. How do I shrink this to be more clean? Basically to add ".." to a series of sequential numbers.
I am using Perl, but I'm just not sure of the syntax to make it work.

Don't do this in SQL, do it in a real programming language. I don't think there's any easy way in SQL to find the gaps and merge all the consecutive numbers.

Provide a sample, CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO with short data (5-7 rows, 2-3 consecutive values groups, including 1-value group) and show desired output for this data.

More specifically, use a language that has arrays.

If you had 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10 you want to output 1..3, 5, 7..10?

here is a short query for you
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
  CONCAT( IF(l=h, l, CONCAT(l,"..",h)))
) GAP
FROM ( 
  SELECT MIN(t1.id) l,MAX(t1.id) h, MAX(IF(t2.id IS NULL,@grp:=@grp+1,@grp)) AS grp
  FROM id_table t1
  LEFT JOIN id_table t2 ON t2.id = t1.id +1
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @grp := 0 ) AS INIT
  GROUP BY @grp
) as r;

result
100..103,110,120..121,200..203,400,500

sample
dbfiddle

This is a variation on the "gaps and islands" problem.
First, match up each ID with its previous ID.
select 
  id, 
  lag(id) over(order by id) as prev_id 
from test

If we have 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12 this produces...



id
prev_id




1
null


2
1


3
2


5
3


7
5


8
7


9
8


10
9


12
10



Now we can find the start of each group by finding the rows where id - prev_id <> 1, or if prev_id is null. That's 1, 5, 7, and 12 above. The end is the prev_id of the next matching row. If there is no next row, the end is the highest ID.
with lag_ids as (
  select 
    id, 
    lag(id) over(order by id) as prev_id
  from test
)
select 
  id as start, 
  coalesce(
    lead(prev_id) over(order by id),
    (select max(id) from test)
  ) as end
from lag_ids 
where prev_id is null 
   or id - prev_id <> 1




start
end




1
3


5
5


7
10


12
12



We can then format this using a case statement to identify groups of one ID.
with lag_ids as (
  select 
    id, 
    lag(id) over(order by id) as prev_id 
  from test
),
start_end as (
  select 
    id as start, 
    coalesce(
      lead(prev_id) over(order by id),
      (select max(id) from test)
    ) as end
  from lag_ids 
  where prev_id is null 
     or id - prev_id <> 1
)
select
  case
  when start = end then start
  when start < end then concat(start, '..', end)
  else 'error'
  end as id_range
from start_end
order by start




id_range




1..3


5


7..10


12



You can then group concat the case to get 1..3,5,7..10,12.
Demonstration.

Perl's Set::IntSpan module does this:
$ perl -MSet::IntSpan -E 'say Set::IntSpan->new(\@ARGV)->run_list' 1 6 2 7 3 8
1-3,6-8

